# List not outputting any data (System.DirectoryServices)

Tags: c#, list, methods, active-directory

I currently have a method that queries for Canonical Name and the CN of a specified machine. Although, when validating the data within the method, nothing is outputted. I'm not sure if I've formatted something incorrectly or didn't filter properly. I've tried a number of things (changing the format of `search.Filter`), etc., to no avail. Below is the latest code I have. I'm hoping someone will see something that I am missing.

```
    public class ComputersCheck
    {
        public string OU { get; set; }
        public string ComputerName { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return OU + " " + " " + ComputerName;
        }
    }
    public List<ComputersCheck> GetOU(string PCName)
    {
            List<ComputersCheck> Computers = new List<ComputersCheck>().ToList();
            string DomainPath = "LDAP://DC=DOMAIN,DC=COM"; 
            DirectoryEntry searchRoot = new DirectoryEntry(DomainPath); 
            DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
            search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=Computer)(computerName=MACHINE_NAME))"; 
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("CN");
            search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("Canonical Name"); 
            SearchResult result;
            SearchResultCollection resultCol = search.FindAll();

            if (resultCol != null)
            {
                for (int counter = 0; counter < resultCol.Count; counter++)
                {
                    string ComputerNameOUString = string.Empty;
                    result = resultCol[counter];
                    if(result.Properties.Contains("CN") &&
                       result.Properties.Contains("Canonical Name"))
                    {
                        ComputersCheck objSurveyComputers = new ComputersCheck();
                        objSurveyComputers.ComputerName = (String)result.Properties["CN"][0];
                        objSurveyComputers.OU = (String)result.Properties["Canonical Name"][0];
                        Computers.Add(objSurveyComputers);
                    }
                }
            }

        foreach (ComputersCheck computer in Computers)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(computer);

        }
        search.Dispose();
        searchRoot.Dispose();
        return Computers;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have a few things that need to be corrected:

1. There is no `computerName` attribute. The attribute you're after is called [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-samaccountname), which is the same attribute used for the username for user accounts. However, for computers, it is the computer name followed by the `$` character. So your search should look like this:

```
(&(objectClass=computer)(sAMAccountName=MACHINE_NAME$))
```

2. Attribute names never have spaces. You want the [`canonicalName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-canonicalname) attribute. I see you are assigning it to a property called `OU`. Just be aware that the `canonicalName` includes the name of the object itself at the end, not just the OU.

```
search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("canonicalName");
...
objSurveyComputers.OU = (String)result.Properties["canonicalName"][0];
```

3. You are calling `.Dispose()` on a couple objects, which is fine (although not absolutely needed). But the most important one to dispose is `resultCol`, because the [documentation for `SearchResultCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresultcollection?view=netframework-4.8) says:

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.

You can also put it in a [`using` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) instead of calling `.Dispose()` manually, which would have the same effect.

Comment: Thank you for this! This was very well wrote out and I appreciate the help. I plan on modifying the canonicalName value to take out the name of the object itself. I will not be able to test this until tomorrow, but I will respond to this once I do. I was unaware of the `SearchResultCollection` class not releasing all of its unmanaged resources, thank you for this information. The last thing I want is a memory leak that I would've had to dig through 1,000's of lines of code to find.

Comment: No problem. Happy to help. I have documented a few other tips here, although nothing more that you can apply in this specific case: [Active Directory: Better performance](https://www.gabescode.com/active-directory/2018/12/15/better-performance-activedirectory.html)

Comment: Great read. Very detailed and organized for these types of scenario's. Thank you.